# What exactly is an id-expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm having a problem clearly understanding exactly what an `id-expression` is. I'll start off by following what I found in the most recent working draft of the C++ standard starting off with:

[image]

Venturing to the definition of an `identifier`:

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits.

So it seems like any arbitrary long sequence of letters and digits can be an `id-expression`, but wait:

[image]

So the `identifier` must be declared first in order for it to be an `id-expression`? Well lets head over to clause 7:

[image]

Continuing...

[image]

Continuing again...

[image]

We arrive here:

[image]

I interpret this to mean an `id-expression` requires an `identifier` to be declared which requires an `id-expression`. This seems like a circular definition. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Anyway, my interpretation is that the identifier must be declared first in order for it to be considered an `id-expression`, but isn't that really just a `name`? The standard states that:

> Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration.

So why not just call it a `name-expression` instead?

Comment: There are names that are not identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

You're misinterpreting [[expr.prim.general]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.general#8):

> An *identifier* is an *id-expression* provided it has been suitably declared (Clause 7).

The phrase's intention is to disallow the usage of undeclared identifiers in expressions. I.e. this paragraph talks about ***id-expression*s occurring as *primary-expression*s**, not *id-expression*s occurring in declarators. I agree that the phrase is misleading and should be fixed. I filed a core issue.

> So why not just call it a *name-expression* instead?

Historical reasons; the subtle distinction between identifiers and names was made after the very fundamental grammatical constructs (*id-expression*, *unqualified-id*, etc.) were named, and from there onwards, renaming those wasn't an option.