# Disambiguating id-expression and type-id in sizeof expressions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm having trouble figuring out how the standard disambiguates `sizeof` [expressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.unary), which can be (among others):

> `sizeof` *unary-expression* 
> `sizeof` `(` *type-id* `)`

For example, I want to know how the standard would distinguish between

> *unary-expression*
>   `sizeof`
>   *unary-expression* ... *primary-expression*
>     `(`
>     *expression* ... *primary-expression*, *id-expression*, *unqualified-id*
>       `identifier`
>     `)`

and

> *unary-expression*
>   `sizeof`
>   `(`
>   *type-id* ... *simple-type-specifier*, *type-name*, *typedef-name*
>     `identifier`
>   `)`

Similar ambiguities arise for the other *type-names* that can be identifiers, I want to understand how this maps to the standard.

**[edit]** 

To clarify: I'm very well able to disambiguate identifiers for a *type-name* according to how they were declared (typedef, class, etc.) - however I currently do not see how *id-expression* (or its contained *unqualified-id*) disambiguates when another parse may match a *type-id*. As brought up in the comments various rules exist for specific cases to disambiguate expressions vs. type-ids, but I don't yet see how they extend to this specific case (unless you extrapolate and assume type-id always wins over expressions, which has been suggested as a possible reading of the disambiguation rules in the comments).
**[end edit]**

My idea was to look for any constraints on what identifier can be an *id-expression*, but I can't find anything specific, the closest to a constraint I can see is the very unhelpful phrasing in [5.1.1/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.prim#general-8)

> An identifier is an id-expression provided it has been suitably declared (Clause 7 [dcl.dcl]).

Looking at the mentioned section I couldn't find what it means to refer to and on the web I've only found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440790/what-exactly-is-an-id-expression) but the answer doesn't go into details beyond

> The phrase's intention is to disallow the usage of undeclared identifiers in expressions.

So either this is resolved differently than I'm thinking, or there must be more meaning to "suitably declared" that I'm missing.

PS: using the C++14 standard has no particular reason, its just what I've been working with at the time, answers for a newer standard are just as fine. Checking the mentioned sections in the newer standards myself didn't seem to have any obvious clarifications.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.ambig.res#2?

Comment: @T.C. I don't see how this would resolve the interpretation of the identifier, since no function style casts are involved; both grammar rules reduce strictly to a single identifier.

Comment: It starts by talking about function-style casts, but the disambiguation rule it lays down is more general: anything that can be a type-id is a type-id.

Comment: @T.C. ok I now see how you're reading it, but if the intention is to set up a general ruling this is very strange wording. Within its paragraph it describes an ambiguity and then says "The resolution [of this ambiguity] is ...", so expecting the reader to assume a general ruling is questionable. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: You may find [_template-argument_](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#nt:template-argument) even more interesting to disambiguate

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I already came across it, yes it was interesting, but so far easily resolvable by following [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#6.3) standard ruling. For the case in this question its unclear where and how the standard specifies how to disambiguate the parsing.

Comment: That's...actually not how *template-argument* is disambiguated: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg#2

Comment: @T.C. actually looking at the _template-parameter-list_ is sufficient for disambiguating most cases, the rule I quoted is even repeated in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg#1 - I probably should have quoted that one instead. I guess the ambiguities in _template-argument_ I encountered so far weren't the "interesting" ones meant by previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [lexer hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexer_hack): whether an *identifier* is an *unqualified-id*, a *type-name*, or a *template-name* is determined based on **declarations** that have already been processed or on the `typename` and `template` parser guides in dependent contexts.  This is the only way to distinguish, say, the interpretations of `A * b;` as a *simple-declaration* of a pointer or as an *expression-statement* that discards the result of a multiplication.

The standard is very **vague** about this: it merely mentions the interpretation of an identifier that appears in a declaration in places like [class.pre]/1:

> Its name becomes a *class-name* ([class.name]) within its scope.

[temp.param]/3:

> A *type-parameter* whose *identifier* does not follow an ellipsis defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* (if declared without `template`) or *template-name* (if declared with `template`) in the scope of the template declaration.

[temp.local]/1, where it’s also dependent on syntax:

> The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.

and [temp.names]/3, where it is part of a note because the normative text specifies the interpretation of a `<`:

> [*Note 1*: If the name is an *identifier*, it is then interpreted as a *template-name*.  […]  — *end note*]

Comment: I'm well aware of that, I'm looking for how the standard mandates which parsing to chose based on the knowledge about the identifier (if thats how it disambiguates this syntax)

Comment: Making this even more "interesting", template template arguments use the *id-expression* production. "Declarations and how to parse them" one day?

Comment: @Zarat: It barely does, which is why that wasn’t my first thought—but I added some citations to demonstrate the meagre specification.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the quoted parts seem to bear any relevance to the question, which is about _id-expression_ (or _unqualified-id_) conflicting with all the others - or maybe I'm still missing your point. I can disambiguate _type-name_ into _typedef-name_ instead of _class-name_ etc. easily enough, but I'm missing the reasoning how it disallows using them in _id-expressions_ (and more specifically, what exactly it allows there)

Comment: @Zarat: If a name (say) “becomes a *class-name*”, then it is thereafter ineligible to be interpreted as an *unqualified-id* (which has no production from *class-name*), no?

Comment: Yes, that would be similar to what I'm describing in the question as for what I'm looking for, some constraint on _unqualified-id_ or _id-expression_ that I'm missing. Though _unqualified-id_ is also used in _using-declaration_, and it feels like those would break if your suggestion were true, so I don't want to jump to conclusions without something to back it up.

Comment: If you think thats how it works though, feel free to add to your answer, especially if you have something to back up this interpretation.